# Доступ к request.user из модели Django

Tags: python, django

Пишу сайт на Django. Есть такая проблема: Есть модель Client для почти везде на сайте пользователю надо выводить его клиентов.
Вначале писал в каждом виде так:

```
Client.objects.filter(user=request.user)
```

Потом в сделал свой Менеджер с методом в который надо передавать пользователя, но вообщем это не избавляет от проблемы постоянно передавать пользователя. Как можно сделать что бы текущий пользователь был доступен в models.py?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вообще это нарушает логику работы Django. Там предлагается таскать объект `Request` вручную, и, да, делать `Client.objects.filter(user=request.user)`. Если это делается много раз, можно ведь и в функцию оформить:

```
# models.py
...
def own_clients(request):
    return Client.objects.filter(user=request.user)
...
```

И, соответственно, пользоваться:

```
# views.py
from .models import ..., own_clients
...
    ... = own_clients(request).all()
```

С другой стороны, в принципе, сделать копию `request` локальной для потока:

```
# middleware.py

import threading

_local_storage = threading.local()

class CurrentRequestMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request):
        _local_storage.request = request

def get_current_request():
    return getattr(_local_storage, "request", None)

def get_current_user():
    request = get_current_request()
    if request is None:
        return None
    return getattr(request, "user", None)
```

В `settings.py` добавить в `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` этот `CurrentRequestMiddleware` и далее использовать, как и у Вас:

```
# models.py

from django.db import models
from .middleware import get_current_user

class OwnManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = super(OwnManager, self).get_queryset()
        return qs.filter(user=get_current_user())

class Client(models.Model):
    ...

    own_objects = OwnManager()
```

Но все это будет работать до тех пор, пока не поменяется внутреннее устройство фреймворка, а гарантий, что на каждый запрос создается отдельный поток никто не давал (хотя по факту это, вроде бы, и так). Например, я бы не поручился за работоспособность этого при использовании совместно с django-gevent.

Answer (score 2):

Покажи модель Client и "почти везде" это где, на фронте?

Если я правильно понял тебя, то почему бы не сделать так?

```
class Client(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('User', verbose_name="user", related_name="clients")
    ...
```

потом на фронте получаешь клиентов так {{ request.user.clients.all }}